# Django DRF authentication and permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am currently using DRF and django-allauth for authentication to my website. What should I use to only allow specific users who have an account on my website to use the DRF on the website? Some users I would like to only allow GET and some users I would like to allow GET, PUT, POST for the API.

Comment: Could you be more specific about the case?? Authentication in drf is a really vast topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DRF, you can define custom permissions that allow you to restrict access to your api based on the request method used.

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions

you can then set this permissions as the default permission class in the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES in your REST_FRAMEWORK settings. Or you can also set it in your view with permission_classes.